# How to pass a parameter into a subquery in a join statement

Tags: sql-server, join, query

I have a query that should be implemented in an MSSQL View so no local variables allowed, this query is working but it has to call a function to return a temporary table, this function is called inside a subquery, inside a left join, and I get the multi-part identifier .... can not be bound error. The query looks like this:

```
Select a, b, c,...., z From  tablea
left join (select * from fnGetTempTable (tablea.pkid) t1 on tablea.id = t1.id
left join ....etc
```

This temporary table returned by the function requires the parameter that tablea has, but I can't get it to that level, any suggestions please?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community, please tag your SQL Server version and have a look at; [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: "joining to a function to return a table" sounds like you're actually looking to do an `APPLY` (specifically an `OUTER APPLY` which behaves similar to a `LEFT JOIN` https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer apply`.

Note, however, that in an apply, the entire inner `select` is logically evaluated per row. So the results may be different from what you'd expect from a join, where rows are matched based on the `on` clause. (Obviously the compiler may choose other strategies, the effect will be the same.)

There is no `on` clause, instead use a `where` inside the apply.

Use `cross apply` to simulate an inner join, use `outer apply` for a left join

```sql
Select a, b, c,...., z
From  tablea
outer apply (
  select *
  from fnGetTempTable (tablea.pkid) t1
  where tablea.id = t1.id
) t1
left join ....etc
```

Comment: Thanks, the outer apply worked just fine, cheers